# Optimize select query. Used join, Not in and sub query

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am trying to optimize the following query :

```
Select distinct cadData.id FROM CAD_Data cadData 
INNER JOIN Sales_Data SD 
ON cadData.CAD_Acct=SD.CAD_Acct 
and SD.List_Date = (
                    select max(List_Date) 
                    from Sales_Data 
                    where Sales_Data.CAD_Acct=cadData.CAD_Acct 
                   )  
where cadData.GMA_Tag = 101 
AND SD.List_Status NOT IN('ACT','OP','PEND','PSHO','pnd')  
ORDER BY cadData.id asc limit 10
```

Both the table has more than 10 millions rows. CAD_Data table is indexed by CAD_Acct and GMA_Tag column. Besides Sales_data is indexed by CAD_Acct,GMA_Tag,List_Date,List_Status columns. Explain shows [image]

I need some suggestion for optimizing this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then, please [edit] your question to provide the information we need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct cadData.id 
FROM CAD_Data cadData 
INNER JOIN Sales_Data SD 
ON cadData.CAD_Acct=SD.CAD_Acct 
INNER JOIN
(
select CAD_Acct,max(List_Date) AS List_Date 
from Sales_Data
GROUP BY CAD_Acct 
) T
ON SD.List_Date=T.List_Date
AND T.CAD_Acct=cadData.CAD_Acct
where cadData.GMA_Tag = 101 
AND SD.List_Status NOT IN('ACT','OP','PEND','PSHO','pnd')  
ORDER BY cadData.id asc limit 10
```

Comment: In the inner join section( INNER JOIN
(
select max(List_Date) AS List_Date 
from Sales_Data 
where Sales_Data.CAD_Acct=cadData.CAD_Acct 
) T) , it's saying unknown column cadData.CAD_Acct

Comment: Not improved. It's even taking longer time. I think group by is taking more time

Answer (score 0):

Do what Jay suggests, but also provide these indexes:

```
SD:  INDEX(List_Date)
cadData:  INDEX(GMA_Tag, CAD_Acct, id)  -- in this order
```

Jay's reformulation begs for starting with the subquery.  That means that indexes need to exist to handle the tables in a different order.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a new `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these indexes in place:

```
ALTER TABLE `CAD_Data` ADD INDEX `cad_data_idx_tag_id` (`GMA_Tag`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `CAD_Data` ADD INDEX `cad_data_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `CAD_Data` ADD INDEX `cad_data_idx_acct` (`CAD_Acct`);
ALTER TABLE `Sales_Data` ADD INDEX `sales_data_idx_status_acct` (`List_Status`,`CAD_Acct`);
```

Once you created them, try to run this query transformation:

```
SELECT 
    cadData.id
FROM
    CAD_Data cadData
WHERE
    cadData.GMA_Tag = 101 
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            Sales_Data SD
                LEFT JOIN
            Sales_Data AS Sales_Data1 ON Sales_Data1.CAD_Acct = cadData.CAD_Acct
                AND Sales_Data1.List_Date < cadData.CAD_Acct
        WHERE
            cadData.CAD_Acct = SD.CAD_Acct
                AND SD.List_Status NOT IN ('ACT' , 'OP', 'PEND', 'PSHO', 'pnd')
                AND cadData.CAD_Acct IS NULL)
ORDER BY cadData.id ASC
LIMIT 10
```